# Put list with position absolute into middle of div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have small problem with some design.

I have this very simple html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is just a small part of a bigger widget. To make thsi widget work, I need at least this css:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

ul {
    z-index: 99;
}

li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Now I want to put list down into the midst of div. There is no problem with putting it down, but it is impossible for me to put it into middle. List can have any number of items.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBxNU/1/

So far, I tried for example:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But it didnt work and I have no clue why.

If you could give me some help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you set a width and height to it ?

Comment: must the ul be set with position absolute??

Comment: @Patsy Issa - I can set width and height anywhere. But still there can be various items so I can't (shouldnt) set width of ul.

Comment: you have set width:100% on the ul - so it is already centered because it takes up the full width

Comment: You want it vertically or horizontally centered? And what browser support do you need

Comment: @Danield - Feel free to add html elements. UL doesnt need absolute position. (I will correct it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with text-align: center doesn't work because you have floated items inside ul. You can use display: inline-block instead of float:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caprella/r2RjM/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here you are ;)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    list-style: none inside;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

So the main idea is to set `text-align: center` for parent `div` and `display: inline-block` for `ul`, that's it )